# Vector containing polymorphic objects: static assertion error

Tags: c++, vector, static-assert

After not using C++ since college, I'm trying to use a vector with 2 types of child objects, and I've obviously gotten something wrong.

Initially I used a vector of pointers, which worked, but if I understand correctly, that will leak memory when cleared.

The error I'm getting led me to believe that it had something to do with a static counter in the class (destroyed with last member?), but removing that has not solved it.

Error leads here, in stl_construct.h:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
      // A deleted destructor is trivial, this ensures we reject such types:
      static_assert(is_destructible<_Value_type>::value,
            "value type is destructible");
#endif
```

Well, OK, but my destructors are all explicitly declared.  I remembered the parent class should use a virtual destructor and fixed that, but the problem remains all the same.

Moving the constructor/destructor to public on the virtual parent class shouldn't (and indeed didn't) change things.

Right now I'm assuming that I'm misusing the vector somehow.  Here's my example:

main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Foo.h"
#include <iostream>
Bar buildBar();

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::vector<Foo> Foos;
    Foos.reserve(1);
    Foos.push_back(buildBar());
    for (int idx=(0);sizeof(Foos);idx++)
    {
        try {
            std::cout <<  "x = " << Foos.at(idx).getLoc().at(0);
        }
        catch (std::exception& e) {
                std::cout <<  idx << ": Index out of range" << std::endl;
            }
    }
Foos.clear();
return 0;
}

Bar buildBar()
{
    Bar* temp = new Bar(5,6);
    return *temp;
}
```

Foo.h, with the constructor moved to header:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H
#include <vector>
class Foo
{
public:
    //int maxoID(){return lastoID;} //0-indexed
    /* Other things */
    virtual std::vector<int> getLoc(){ return {x_Base,y_Base};}
    Foo(): 
    //oID(-1), 
    x_Base(-1),
    y_Base(-1){}
    virtual ~Foo(){}
protected:
    int x_Base;
    int y_Base;
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
    Bar(int x1, int y1):
        x_End(-1),
        y_End(-1)
        { 
            x_Base = x1; 
            y_Base = y1;
        }
    ~Bar(){}
    std::vector<int> getLoc() {return {x_Base,y_Base,x_End,y_End};}
protected:
    int x_End;
    int y_End;

};

#endif // FOO_H
```

Comment: Your `buildBar()` function is a memory leak.

Comment: "_Initially I used a vector of pointers, which worked, but if I understand correctly, that will leak memory when cleared._" So, why didn't you use `std::vector` of `std::unique_ptr`? Related read: [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: `sizeof(Foos)` doesn't tell you how many items are in the vector. (it tells you how many bytes it occupies excluding its contained data).

Comment: You're encountering [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). Consider using `std::unique_ptr` or `std::reference_wrapper`. A `vector` of raw pointers doesn't leak memory, unless you expect the `vector` to maintain ownership. You need to manage the memory yourself.

Comment: Polymorphism only works with pointers or references to the base class, so you cannot have `std::vector<Foo>` and expect anything to work.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, good on your for questioning your use of raw pointers! Too often people just blindly use them, and it will eventually lead to other problems.

Your current problem is that you have [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). When you insert a `Bar` into a `vector<Foo>` you lose critical information about `Bar`. The same happens if you call a function which takes only a `Foo`, not a `Foo&` or `Foo*`.

Depending on your use, you can either use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), or [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)

Note that you *can* use raw pointers, and they won't just automatically leak memory, but the `vector` will not be responsible for the memory (which is the beauty of using one of the smart pointers I pointed out)

This is completely acceptable:

```
int main()
{
    Foo* f = new Foo;
    {
        std::vector<Foo*> v;
        v.push_back(f);
    } // v goes out of scope and is cleaned up
    delete f; // the vector won't have cleaned this up, it's our responsibility    
}
```

Using `unique_ptr` instead just makes this a whole lot less complicated. Of course in such a light example raw pointer is easy to use, but in a larger program it can get out of control:

Note also, and as [@juanchopanza points out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47862695/vector-containing-polymorphic-objects-static-assertion-error/47862983#comment82690361_47862695), your `buildBar` function leaks memory. When you call

```
return *temp;
```

You create a copy and you'll lose the memory address of `temp` and therefore be unable to delete it.

```
Bar buildBar()
{
    Bar* temp = new Bar(5,6);
    return *temp;
}

Bar b = buildBar();
Bar* p = &b; // this only reference the copy, b
delete p; // this is bad, this will (double) delete the memory from b, which is not the same as temp.
```

`b` will be cleaned up automatically when it goes out of scope (which is bad if you've also tried to delete it), but you've no way to delete the `temp`

Answer (score 2):

Welcome back to C++!

You can't put derived types in a vector of base types. The instances can be of base type only. If you try to add a derived type to this vector, it will only copy the base parts of the derived class.

You were right the first time--You need a vector of base pointers. This will not leak as long as you delete the pointers when removing them from the vector.

However, this is 2017 and we now like to avoid new/deletes in general. So you could use a vector of unique_ptr (C++'11), which auto-delete the memory when they go out of scope.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>> v;
v.push_back(std::make_unique<Bar>(0, 0));
```

You could also use a vector of variants (C++'17), which are the newfangled typesafe union.

```
typedef std::variant<Bar, Foo> MyBar
std::vector<MyBar> v;
```

use `std::visit` or `std::get` on an element to get its type back.

**EDIT: Here is some code to extract the elements from a vector of variants**

```
bool apply(int& i)
{
    std::cout << "integer: " << i << std::endl;
    return true;
}

bool apply(double& d)
{
    std::cout << "double: " << d << std::endl;
    return true;
}

void test()
{
    typedef std::variant<int, double> asdf;

    std::vector<asdf> v;

    v.push_back(10);
    v.push_back(0.5);

    auto myLambda = [](auto&& arg) { return apply(arg); };  // use of auto (the 2nd one) is required.

    for (auto& elem : v)
    {
        std::visit(myLambda, elem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm reading up on the variant now.  Would it allow me directly access public functions of a child class without either declaring them virtual in the parent class or recasting?  Since this is for my own use, throwing exceptions on operations applied to the wrong class is acceptable and probably even desirable.

Comment: Yes. Since you're not using pointers, the compiler can determine the function linkage at compile time and doesn't use dynamic binding at all. In fact, the types don't have to be related.

Comment: I added an example of how to use the elements in your vector of variants.